# C++ How to Check what words aren't in 2 similar files

Tags: c++, c++98

i was trying to find a way to check two different files and get, from the second, all lines that aren't in the first.. but does all the opposite.

I tried the possible to solve this but nothing...

This is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
char username[UNLEN+1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
GetUserName(username, &username_len);

stringstream buffer;
buffer << "C:\\Users\\" << username << "\\Desktop\\";
stringstream buffer2;
buffer2 << "C:\\Users\\" << username << "\\Desktop\\Legit.txt";
stringstream buffer3;
buffer3 << "C:\\Users\\" << username << "\\Desktop\\Unlegit.txt";
stringstream buffer4;
buffer4 << "C:\\Users\\" << username << "\\Desktop\\result.txt";

string results = buffer4.str();

int offset;
int num;
num = 1;
string search;
string linea;
string legit;
string unlegit;
string line;

cout << "Is the Legit.txt file at '" << buffer.str() << "'? [Y/N]: ";
cin >> legit;
if (legit == "Y" || legit == "y"){
}else if(legit == "N" || legit == "n"){
    return 0;
}else{
    cout << "\n.";
    return 0;
}
string legitfile = buffer2.str();

cout << "\nIs the Unlegit.txt file at '" << buffer.str() << "'? [Y/N]: ";
cin >> unlegit;
if (unlegit == "Y" || unlegit == "y"){
}else if(unlegit == "N" || unlegit == "n"){
    return 0;
}else{
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
string unlegitfile = buffer3.str();

ifstream file(legitfile.c_str());
if(file.is_open()){
while(getline(file, line)){
    ifstream MyFile(unlegitfile.c_str());

    if(MyFile.is_open()){
        while(!MyFile.eof()){
            getline(MyFile,linea);
            if((offset = linea.find(line, 0)) != string::npos) {
                cout << "\n[" << num << "]" << " Word Found: " << line << "\n";
                num++;
                fstream result(results.c_str());
                result << line << "\n";
                result.close();
            }
        }
        MyFile.close();
    }
}
file.close();
return 0;
}else{
cout << "\nThe file '" << legitfile << "' does not exist.";
cout << "\nThe file '" << unlegitfile << "' does not exist.";
}
}
```

As i said, This code checks which words are equals in both (first & second) files and, once found, writes them to a third file, there is a way to do the opposite (check the two files and get the words that aren't equals)? Thank you so much!

I'm new, both in the forum and in C++, sorry if I make any mistakes. (sorry for my bad english too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic solution to this sort of problem is to use a hash table collection to represent all the words in the first file.  Then while iterating items from the second file, consult the set constructed of the first file.  In C++, the `std::unordered_set` will do fine.

```
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

unordered_set<string> firstFileSet;
unordered_set<string> missingFromSecondFileSet;
string line;

while(!firstfile.eof())
{
    getline(firstfile,line);
    firstFileSet.insert(line);
}
```

Then for each word in the second file, use a second set collection to keep track of what words are missing.

```
while(!secondfile.eof())
{
    getline(secondfile,line);

    if (firstFileSet.find(line) != firstFileSet.end())
    {
        missingFromSecondFileSet.insert(line);
    }
    else
    {
        firstFileSet.erase(line);
    }
}
```

After the above runs, `firstFileSet` contains all the lines in the first file that were not present in the second.  `missingFromSecondFileSet` contains all the lines in the second file that were not in the first:

```
for (auto &s : firstFileSet)
{
    cout << s << " was in the first file, but not the second" << endl;
}

for (auto &s : missingFromSecondFileSet)
{
    cout << s << " was in the second file, but not the first" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called diff on linux which does just what you are looking to do in C++.

It is written in C so you can just copy its source code =P

```
for (;; cmp->file[0].buffered = cmp->file[1].buffered = 0)
{
    /* Read a buffer's worth from both files.  */
    for (f = 0; f < 2; f++)
        if (0 <= cmp->file[f].desc)
            file_block_read (&cmp->file[f],
                buffer_size - cmp->file[f].buffered);

    /* If the buffers differ, the files differ.  */
    if (cmp->file[0].buffered != cmp->file[1].buffered
            || memcmp (cmp->file[0].buffer,
                    cmp->file[1].buffer,
                    cmp->file[0].buffered))
    {
        changes = 1;
        break;
    }

    /* If we reach end of file, the files are the same.  */
    if (cmp->file[0].buffered != buffer_size)
    {
        changes = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Taken from ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/diffutils/diffutils-3.0.tar.gz > src/analyze.c

Comment: I do not want to compare the two files, because if I do it will check if the similar words are in the same line, I want to check if in the second file there are words that in the first there are not.